# Spring Boot with JSF AdminFaces deployment issue in Wildfly 8.2.1

Tags: spring-boot, primefaces, wildfly, joinfaces, adminfaces

I'm trying to deploy my JSF (Primefaces & Adminfaces) Spring Boot project on wildfly 8.2.1, but the following exception was thrown:

```
23:06:30,764 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-10) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."cproj.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."cproj.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "cproj.war"
       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_172]
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_172]
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_172]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017327: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: tomcat-jasper-8.5.34.jar
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadSci(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:207)
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:128)
       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
       ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017327: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: tomcat-jasper-8.5.34.jar
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadSci(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:199)
       ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more from [Module "deployment.cproj.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadSci(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:191)
       ... 7 more

23:06:30,820 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "cproj.war")]) - failure description: {
   "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"cproj.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"cproj.war\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"cproj.war\"
   Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017327: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: tomcat-jasper-8.5.34.jar
   Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017327: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: tomcat-jasper-8.5.34.jar
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more from [Module \"deployment.cproj.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
   "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"cproj.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"cproj.war\".beanmanager]"]
}
23:06:30,886 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "cproj.war" (runtime-name : "cproj.war")
23:06:30,887 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
     service jboss.deployment.unit."cproj.war".beanmanager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."cproj.war".weld.weldClassIntrospector]
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."cproj.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."cproj.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "cproj.war"

23:06:31,816 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment cproj.war (runtime-name: cproj.war) in 710ms
23:06:31,818 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
23:06:31,819 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
23:06:31,820 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" started in 11978ms - Started 202 of 253 services (88 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
23:06:31,935 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "cproj.war" (runtime-name: "cproj.war")
23:06:31,936 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."cproj.war".INSTALL
```

I've tried the answer in this question but still not working

[Error on integrating Primefaces with Springboot/JoinFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61093213/error-on-integrating-primefaces-with-springboot-joinfaces)

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
       <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
       <artifactId>joinfaces-parent</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.6</version>
       <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
   <artifactId>cproj</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <name>cproj</name>
   <description>Non-IFC Sales Entry project</description>

   <properties>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
       <joinfaces.version>4.1.1</joinfaces.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
           <artifactId>security-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
           <version>${joinfaces.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
           <artifactId>adminfaces-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
                   <artifactId>tomcat-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
           <artifactId>jsf-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
                   <artifactId>tomcat-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <!-- Dependencies which will be provided by WildFly -->
       <!-- START -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
           <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
           <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
           <artifactId>undertow-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
           <artifactId>weld-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <!-- END -->

       <!-- jasper reports -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
           <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
           <version>6.13.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
           <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
           <version>6.13.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <!-- Upload Function -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
           <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
           <version>3.17</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
           <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
           <version>3.17</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
           <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
           <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
           <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency>
       <!-- Oracle JDBC driver -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
           <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
           <version>19.3.0.0</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.github.adminfaces</groupId>
               <artifactId>admin-template</artifactId>
               <version>1.1.1</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.github.adminfaces</groupId>
               <artifactId>admin-theme</artifactId>
               <version>1.1.0</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
               <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
               <version>8.0</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
               <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
               <version>8.0</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   <build>
       <finalName>cproj</finalName>
       <resources>
           <resource>
               <filtering>true</filtering>
               <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
           </resource>
           <resource>
               <directory>src/main/docs</directory>
               <filtering>true</filtering>
           </resource>
       </resources>
       <testResources>
           <testResource>
               <filtering>true</filtering>
               <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
           </testResource>
           <testResource>
               <directory>src/test/java/</directory>
           </testResource>
       </testResources>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   <repositories>
       <repository>
           <id>prime-repo</id>
           <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
           <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
           <layout>default</layout>
       </repository>
       <repository>
           <id>spring-snapshots</id>
           <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
           <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
           <snapshots>
               <enabled>true</enabled>
           </snapshots>
       </repository>
       <repository>
           <id>spring-milestones</id>
           <name>Spring Milestones</name>
           <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
       </repository>
   </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: 1) I don't see you using the JoinFaces PrimeFaces Starter? 2) the error is with Tomcat Jasper jar so try removing Jasper reports first to see if that is the issue.

Comment: adminfaces-spring-boot-starter >
Template and Theme starter for AdminFaces. Pulls primefaces-spring-boot-starter.

Comment: by the way, same pom is working for another project with bootsfaces rather than adminfaces

Comment: I've removed Jasper report but still the same

Comment: i would notify the AdminFaces developer and JoinFaces developers then.

Comment: I found someone reported this before but no response :'(